# Would contributing to Apache Flex Compiler improve Adobe Flex Compiler?

Tags: apache, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Adobe has done some confusing things with Flash/Flex, one of them being donating some part of it to Apache Foundation, creating the Apache Flex (mirror?) project. The latest Flash AS3 compiler being codenamed "Falcon", is supposed to build better and faster code. Falcon is [OSS on github](https://github.com/apache/flex-falcon) under the Apache Flex project. Would contributing to this repo help the main Adobe Flex build? Is there even an Adobe Flex compiler (mxmlc.exe) or is it just Apache Flex from here onwards?

On the [Flex roadmap](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/whitepapers/roadmap.html) Adobe states that :

> **Falcon compiler contribution to Apache**
>
> Falcon 1.0 is the next generation compiler for ActionScript and is
>   currently in development. Upon completion of the ActionScript portion
>   of the compiler, Adobe will contribute Falcon 1.0 to the Apache Flex
>   Project, which we expect will be in Q4 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flex SDK is fully donated to Apache and is now under very active development there.
Flash Builder is still maintained by Adobe, but I don't think they will ever release a new version. The Apache Flex SDK is fully compatible to Flash Builder.
Falcon is also under the wings of Apache, but there is no official release yet, because it has still some limitations.

So the simple answer to your question would be: 
Yes, contributing to the Falcon project would help - not to Adobe, but to Apache and finally to you and the Flex development community!

For more informations take a look at the [Apache Flex website](http://flex.apache.org):

- [Falcon Overview](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Falcon+Overview)
- [Falcon GIT repository](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-falcon.git)
- [Bug tracker for Apache Falcon 1.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX/fixforversion/12324433?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:version-summary-panel)
- [Search for Falcon in the Users Mailing List](http://apache-flex-users.2333346.n4.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=search_page&node=1&query=subject%3Afalcon&days=0)
- [Development Forum](http://s.apache.org/flex-dev-forum)

Comment: Is Adobe Flex SDK completely replaced by Apache Flex SDK? Would FlashDevelop users have to switch to Apache Flex for latest features?

Comment: Correct, new development is only happening in Apache Flex.

Comment: You forgot to mention that Apache Flex SDK can only target older versions of AIR (Air 4.6 / 4.7) although the Adobe Flex SDK can target the latest versions like 13, 14, 15, etc.

Comment: Isn't it the opposite? The release notes for Apache Flex SDK (4.13, released july 2014) say that they support AIR up to version 14.